# Bot Framework performance best practices

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker

Not sure if this is the right place for this question.

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework for the implementation of a Teams chatbot in combination with QnaMaker. Pretty straightforward however, the bot should be used by 300 users. There will be a lot of concurrent use. Up until now I used to implement customer facing chatbots on website and Facebook pages (not much concurrent usage).

I searched for any best practices on the implementation of chatbot with many concurrent users but can't find any.

Questions I have:

1. Is QnaMaker able to handle loads of requests from concurrent
   users?
2. Is the Microsoft Bot Service able to handle loads of
   requests from concurrent users?
3. Are there any best practices wrt appservice plans and search plans for these kinds of scenarios

Any guidance to documents with relevant information is much appreciated.

Comment: You can look at following Bot design principle documentation which gives you picture about developing bot using best practices [Bot Services design principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-principles?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), [Azure bot design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-knowledge-base?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), [Build conversational Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/ai/conversational-bot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure handles scaling for you. It's likely that you haven't found answers to your questions because it's a non-issue. Chatbots are assumed to be able to handle many concurrent users by default. The Azure Bot Service would hardly be useful if it couldn't do that.

> Is QnaMaker able to handle loads of requests from concurrent users?

Yes.

> Is the Microsoft Bot Service able to handle loads of requests from concurrent users?

Yes.

> Are there any best practices wrt appservice plans and search plans for these kinds of scenarios

Choose a pricing plan that matches the amount of traffic you expect to get, and change the plan later if you need to.

Comment: would you have more details on where such a "pricing plan" can be tuned ? I see a "Pricing" section in the admin page of my bot, but it only offers F0 (Free) and S1 (Standard). Following the "learn more" link, I get told that "Azure Bot Service (App Service run as standard Azure Web App)" are also subject to pricing, but I have no idea where to tune that pricing. Thanks

Comment: @ArnaudP - You would access the resources in the Azure Portal